# Filter output of 'ps aux'

Tags: unix, grep

running `ps aux` returns :

```
 USER     131 2.1  0.1 23423 423 FFF/5    R    10:12   0:00 -bash
 USER     131 2.1  0.1 23423 423 FFF/5    R    10:12   0:00 -test
 USER     131 2.1  0.1 23423 423 FFF/5    R    10:12   0:00 -test1
```

Attempting to filter on bash with wildcards so just

> USER     131 2.1  0.1 23423 423 FFF/5    R    10:12   0:00 -bash

is returned :

```
ps aux|grep "*bash*"
```

which returns :

```
invalid option : 

    grep: invalid option -- 'p'
    Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
    Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

How to filter the output for `bash` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should just use `ps aux|grep 'bash'` and it will work the way you want.The `*` when used in the `grep` command actually refers to the regex repetition operator of "zero or more" , not the `*` wildcard character.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux | grep bash | grep -v bash
```

to return all bash process

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of `ps` support this directly. For example, to list all processes whose name is `bash`, run `ps` like this:

```
ps -C bash
```